# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by(output started)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, header

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
  $err = [];
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$_POST['username']))
  {
    $err[] = "Логин может состоять только из букв английского алфавита и цифр";
  }
  if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3 or strlen($_POST['username']) > 30)
  {
    $err[] = "Логин должен быть не меньше 3-х символов и не больше 30";
  }
  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['username'])."'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
  {
    $err[] = "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует в базе данных";
  }
  if(count($err) == 0)
  {
  mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO users SET firstname='".$_POST['name']."', username='".$_POST['username']."', pass='".$_POST['pass']."', fulladdress='".$_POST['address']."', phone='".$_POST['phone']."'");
  echo('Добро пожаловать '.$_POST['username'].'');
  header ('Location: autorisation.php');
  }
  else
  {
    echo  "<p style='color:red'>При регистрации произошли следующие ошибки:</p><br>";
    foreach($err AS $error)
    {
      print "<p>$error</p><br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Я понимаю, из-за чего возникает эта ошибка, но просто не могу понять где у меня эти пробелы. В  у меня пробелов тоже нет. Если есть возможность указать на мою ошибку, прошу, сделайте это. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас вывод перед отправкой заголовка:

```
 echo('Добро пожаловать '.$_POST['username'].'');
```

Цитата из документации:

> Помните, что функцию header() можно вызывать только если клиенту еще
>   не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед
>   ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.

[Подробнее](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно помогло, я header поставил выше echo и стало всё работать, только проблема в том, что этот код может находиться только в самом верху файла, я хотел поставить его под формы, чтобы он корректно выводил сообщения, н ок сожалению, так он отказывается работать

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ,  пометьте его как решение